# Role based routing with react-router v6.4+ using createBrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to implement role-based routing with createBrowserRouter?

I want the same routes(ex. "/", "/profile", "dashboard") depending on the user role logged in to be rendered with the different components(ex. ClientProfile, OwnerProfile, DeliveryProfile).
And when it's public, for no logged-in user I want only some routes to be enabled(ex. "/" - for MainPage).

I can create several distinguished routes with createBrowserRouter(ex. ClientRouter, OwnerRouter, etc.) and provide the right one based on the app state to the RouterProvider:`<RouterProvider router={appRouter} />`

But it looks like a wrong approach and too cumbersome relative to the previous version of the dynamically rendered routes when it could be implemented easily by conditional rendering.

```
export const PublicRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    Component: () => <Outlet />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <MainPage></MainPage>,
      },
      {
        path: "/signup",
        element: <SignUp></SignUp>,
      },
    ],
  },
]);


export const OwnerRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    Component: () => <Outlet />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <LoggedIn></LoggedIn>,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```